# New to AS3, unable to get player to move properly

Tags: actionscript-3, game-physics

Like the title says, I'm new to AS3/Flash and trying to learn how to make games.
I've been following the tutorials from Gary Rosenzweig's "Flash Game University" (both the book and the iTunes podcast).
As a disclaimer, all of the code I"m using comes from the above mentioned tutorials, I did not create them. I'm merely splicing them together to try to make something work differently.

Before I post up the code, let me briefly explain my problem and what I've tried to do to solve it. Basically, I got the game to work fine when I used the tutorial code EXACTLY (it used "catcher.x = mouseX" for movement) , but I wanted to try to make the player ("catcher") move with the left and right arrow keys instead of the mouse. However, when I put that in, the movement becomes erratic, and instead of smoothly moving left and right, the player jumps left and right, gaining speed constantly until it simply jumps off the screen. Needless to say, I have no idea why it does this.

At first, I thought the code for my arrow based movement was wrong, so I copied and pasted it into a separate file to test and it worked fine, so I figure that for some reason the code that makes the rest of the game work was somehow breaking it.

I tried moving the code around to different places, but that didn't fix the problem (in fact, it often made it worse).

I figure that I'm missing something in terms of formatting my code (unfortunately, none of the tutorials I've found cover proper style for AS3 and I don't have any prior coding experience, so my code is probably disgustingly messy/unorganized).

As a final note, I apologize in advance for the messiness of my codeI'm rather new to this and just trying to figure things out.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks for taking the time to read this!

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;


    public class CatchingGame1 extends MovieClip {
        var catcher:Catcher;
        var nextObject:Timer;
        var objects:Array = new Array;
        const speed:Number = 7.0;
        var score:int = 0;
        var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
        var rightArrow:Boolean = false;

        public function CatchingGame1() {
            catcher = new Catcher();
            catcher.y = 350;
            addChild(catcher);
            setNextObject();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveObjects);

        }

        public function setNextObject() {
            nextObject = new Timer(Math.random()*1000,1);
            nextObject.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newObject);
            nextObject.start();
        }

        public function newObject(e:Event) {
            var goodObjects:Array = ["Circle1","Circle2"];
            var badObjects:Array = ["Square1","Square2"];
            if(Math.random() < .5) {
                var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*goodObjects.length);
                var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(goodObjects[r]) as Class;
                var newObject:MovieClip = new classRef();
                newObject.typestr = "good";
            } else {
                r = Math.floor(Math.random()*badObjects.length);
                classRef = getDefinitionByName(badObjects[r]) as Class;
                newObject = new classRef();
                newObject.typestr = "bad";
            }
            newObject.x = Math.random()*500;
            addChild(newObject);
            objects.push(newObject);
            setNextObject();
        }

        public function moveObjects(e:Event) {
            for(var i:int=objects.length-1; i>=0;i--) {
                objects[i].y += speed;
                if(objects[i].y > 400) {
                    removeChild(objects[i]);
                    objects.splice(i,1);
                }
                if(objects[i].hitTestObject(catcher)) {
                    if(objects[i].typestr == "good") {
                        score += 5;
                    } else {
                        score -= 1;
                    }
                    if(score < 0) score = 0;
                    scoreDisplay.text = "Score: " + score;
                    removeChild(objects[i]);
                    objects.splice(i,1);

                }
            }
            //this is where it starts to have problems

            //make arrow booleans true
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCatcher);
            function keyPressedDown(Event:KeyboardEvent){
                if (Event.keyCode == 37){
                    leftArrow = true;
                } else if (Event.keyCode == 39){
                    rightArrow = true;
                }

            }

            function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent) {
                if(event.keyCode == 37){
                    leftArrow = false;
                } else if(event.keyCode == 39){
                    rightArrow = false;
                }
            }
                function moveCatcher(event:Event) {
                    var catcherSpeed:Number = 1;
                    if(leftArrow){
                        catcher.x -= catcherSpeed;
                    } 
                    if(rightArrow){
                        catcher.x += catcherSpeed;
                    }
                }



        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the addition of keyUp, keyDown event handlers into your constructor.

Don't use multiple ENTER_FRAME event handlers, just call moveCatcher in your moveObjects 
function.

You seem to have a missing } at the end of your moveObjects method, I edited that. See if that helps.

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;


public class CatchingGame1 extends MovieClip {
    var catcher:Catcher;
    var nextObject:Timer;
    var objects:Array = new Array;
    const speed:Number = 7.0;
    var score:int = 0;
    var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
    var rightArrow:Boolean = false;

    public function CatchingGame1() {
        catcher = new Catcher();
        catcher.y = 350;
        addChild(catcher);
        setNextObject();

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveObjects);

    }

    public function setNextObject() {
        nextObject = new Timer(Math.random()*1000,1);
        nextObject.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newObject);
        nextObject.start();
    }

    public function newObject(e:Event) {
        var goodObjects:Array = ["Circle1","Circle2"];
        var badObjects:Array = ["Square1","Square2"];
        if(Math.random() < .5) {
            var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*goodObjects.length);
            var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(goodObjects[r]) as Class;
            var newObject:MovieClip = new classRef();
            newObject.typestr = "good";
        } else {
            r = Math.floor(Math.random()*badObjects.length);
            classRef = getDefinitionByName(badObjects[r]) as Class;
            newObject = new classRef();
            newObject.typestr = "bad";
        }
        newObject.x = Math.random()*500;
        addChild(newObject);
        objects.push(newObject);
        setNextObject();
    }

    public function moveObjects(e:Event) 
    {
        moveCatcher(null);
        for(var i:int=objects.length-1; i>=0;i--)  
        {
            objects[i].y += speed;
            if(objects[i].y > 400)
            {
                removeChild(objects[i]);
                objects.splice(i,1);
            }
            if(objects[i].hitTestObject(catcher)) 
            {
                if(objects[i].typestr == "good") 
                {
                    score += 5;
                } else {
                    score -= 1;
                }
                if(score < 0) score = 0;
                scoreDisplay.text = "Score: " + score;
                removeChild(objects[i]);
                objects.splice(i,1);

            }
        }
    }

        function keyPressedDown(Event:KeyboardEvent){
            if (Event.keyCode == 37){
                leftArrow = true;
            } else if (Event.keyCode == 39){
                rightArrow = true;
            }

        }

        function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent) {
            if(event.keyCode == 37){
                leftArrow = false;
            } else if(event.keyCode == 39){
                rightArrow = false;
            }
        }
            function moveCatcher(event:Event) {
                var catcherSpeed:Number = 1;
                if(leftArrow){
                    catcher.x -= catcherSpeed;
                } 
                if(rightArrow){
                    catcher.x += catcherSpeed;
                }
            }



    }

}
}
```